# How to stop Nautilus from showing location along with file/directory name?

Tags: nautilus, 17.04, filemanager

Nautilus is showing file names with full paths instead of just the names. How can I make it display only the base name?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Nautilus **Preferences**. Your **Views** tab will probably look something like this:

[image]

Select **None** in all the drop-down boxes (*First*, *Second* and *Third*) under the **Icon View Captions**.

Comment: @Redbob I should point out that the theme you're using is not well designed for this option. Both the file/folder name and the "Icon View Captions" are of the same colour (black), which is not at all aesthetic. Default theme shows the "Icon View Captions" in grey: https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-cptrpy9ZNPg/V_ytffvGSQI/AAAAAAAAHjM/LMxpYn4WPecNnp09iToe-zHG_6sFIgiJQCLcB/s1600/Screenshot%2Bfrom%2B2016-10-11%2B16-14-02.jpg